# Will this javascript work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a script that uses a text input as a radius to find google map locations within that radius. I did not use form. I used JavaScript to pick the value of the input and append it to the url. I use php $_GET to pick the radius and then use it in the search. The strange thing I noticed was that, I found items within the radius on pc but found nothing on mobile. I have no idea what's wrong. But I was suspecting the javascript / jquery not working on mobile and will like to know if it is possible.
And solutions to make it work.

The html + javascript below and then the php.

```
<p class="caption_j">Radius in <b> MILES </b></p>
        <input class="search_n" value="" name="search_dist" type="text" style="width: 85%;"/>
        <span class="ow_right search_dist_lens ow_ic_lens ow_cursor_pointer" style="display: block;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 26px; height: 26px;"></span>
<script>
var urlsearch = "http://www.website.ml/items/search/type/";

</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var text;


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $(':text.search_n').keypress(function(evt){
            if(evt.which===13)
            {
                if($(':text.search_n').val().length > 0)
                {
                    text = $(':text.search_n').val();
                    location.assign(urlsearch+'nearme?dist='+text);
                } 

            }
        });
        $('.search_dist_lens').click(function(){
            if($(':text.search_n').val().length > 0)
            {
                text = $(':text.search_n').val();
                location.assign(urlsearch+'nearme?dist='+text);
            }
        });
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////


    });
</script>
```

Comment: NO! This will not even work in Desktop browsers. **1.** In click handler you're not getting the value of the textbox **2.** `dist` variable value is not what you think it is **3.** When the value of `dist` is not entered(_provided you got the current value now_) and button is clicked, you'll get error _Cannot get length of undefined_ **4.** If you think that `click` event will not work(_as I don't see anything else that may not work on mobile devices_), it'll work. I'll also recommend you to have a look at `touchStart` event

Comment: Please this is the real code giving the error.  Check it again and tell me what to do. I just updated the question.